# Why 'Show less' is not working in my code?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show 3 `<li>` elements and hide the rest. Once I do this, I get a click on that says 'Show more'. When I click 'Show more', it displays the rest of the things. Now I want to see fewer `<li>` elements. When I click on 'Show less', that's not functioning.

```
 <ul class="what-ul">
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
   <li>Lorem ipsum</li>  
</ul>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var count = $('.what-ul').children().length;

    if(count > 3){
      $('.what-ul li:gt(3)').hide()
      $('.what-ul').append("<div class='btn-show'><a class='show-button-6'>... Show more</a></div>");
    } else {
      $('.what-ul li:gt(3)').show();
    }

    $('.show-button-6').click(function() {
      $('.what-ul li:gt(3)').show();
      $('.what-ul').append("<div class='btn-show'><a class='show-button-less-6'>Show less</a></div>");
      $('.show-button-6').hide();
    });

    $('.show-button-less-6').click(function() {
      $('.what-ul li:gt(3)').hide();
      $('.what-ul').append("<div class='btn-show'><a class='show-button-6'>... Show more</a></div>");
      $('.show-button-less-6').hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're attempting to attach event listeners to elements that don't yet exist on the DOM.

You're attaching on document.ready, but when document.ready is fired, you haven't yet created your show-less / show-more elements and appended them to the DOM, meaning the listener has nothing to be attached to.

You have 2 possible solutions to this:

1. Attach your listener to the body, but have it listen to clicks on the button elements, like so:

   ```
   $('body').on('click', '.show-button-6', function() {
       // Listener code here
   });
   ```
2. Create your buttons in the HTML (instead of jQuery) and have them hidden, then just toggle their visibility. It's also better performance-wise to just have them hide/show instead of appending new buttons.

*Bonus*
Please note that you're appending new buttons but you're not destroying the previous ones, you're only hiding them. That means you have tons of duplicated buttons on the DOM.
If you're not going with my second solution, at least change your code to this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var count = $('.what-ul').children().length;

  if(count > 3){
   $('.what-ul li:gt(3)').hide()
   $('.what-ul').append("<div class='btn-show'><a class='show-button-6'>... Show more</a></div>");
   }
  else{
    $('.what-ul li:gt(3)').show();
    }

  $('body').on('click', '.show-button-6', function() {
  $('.what-ul li:gt(3)').show();
  $('.what-ul').append("<div class='btn-show'><a class='show-button-less-6'>Show less</a></div>");
  $('.show-button-6').remove();
});

  $('body').on('click', '.show-button-less-6', function() {
   $('.what-ul li:gt(3)').hide();
   $('.what-ul').append("<div class='btn-show'><a class='show-button-6'>... Show more</a></div>");
   $('.show-button-less-6').remove();
 });
});
```

It will make sure the previous button is destroyed when appending the other version (more / less).

Edit: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6bw3xgc/)

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/t2jd4k87/   , if i click on show-more it is expanding other list also

Comment: In second list why it is not showing starting four li elements?

Comment: Your count is too general and actually counts across the entire page, instead of each list:   var count = $('.dynamic-ul').children().length;
You need a counter per list.